# Searching text in PDF without embedded fonts in iOS

Tags: ios, search, pdf, fonts

I am using FastPdfKit and PDFKitten to search texts in a PDF in iOS. Searching works fine for PDFs with embedded fonts. If the font is not embedded, both libraries fail to give the correct location of the searched text.

If I open the PDFs in Preview (Mac) and use Duplicate function of Preview. The generated PDFs will have embedded fonts and will work correctly when searched using FastPdfKit and PDFKitten.

Should I programmatically recreate the PDF with the font embedded? But not sure on how to actually do this.

Or are there other workarounds for FastPdfKit or PDFKitten for this?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I know question is too old but i think this will surely help others https://github.com/Jageen/PDFSearch

Comment: @Jageen, Nice one. Does this support all the fonts available ? Because PDFKitten doesn't support all the fonts for search functionality.

Comment: @Sravan I believe YES because what i used is fireforx's javascript if they support then this too